# Finding diameter of a circular pie

Tags: geometry, area

A circular pie was cut into 9 pieces in a unique way. First, a circle with a radius of 5 cm was cut from the center of the pie. Then the remaining pie was cut into eight congruent pieces. If the area of the top of each of the 9 pieces is equal, what is the diameter of the pie?

It's been years since I've done math and my work posted this question today for pie day and it's bothering me that I can't remember how to solve it.

Comment: A hint: the center cut of 5cm radius is 1/9 of the total pie.

Comment: yes thank you!, i thought that was too simple but now im realizing if i just had the whole area of the pie i can work backwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The area of a circle is $\pi\cdot r^2$ so area of small circle is $25\pi$

So, the area of all the congruent pieces is $25\pi$

$9\cdot25\pi = 225 \pi$

Divide by $\pi$, then take the root to get

$r=15$

So, diameter is $30$.